# Interpretation of expected prediction error from .632 bootstrap

Tags: bootstrap

I'm examining the internal validity of a developed model using SPSS CATREG with .632 resampling. I am struggling to interpret what the below results, particularly the expected prediction error from the .632 bootstrap, actually means. That is, in their entirety, do the below statistics indicate that the developed model is effective in predicting the outcome?

MODEL SUMMARY
Multiple R = .563;
R squared = .317;
Adjusted R Squared = .292;
Apparent Prediction Error = .683;

Expected Prediction Error from .632 bootstrap
  Estimate = .754;
  Standard error = .074;

ANOVA 
F = 12.548; 
P = < .001;